# How can I make Windows Server start my Apache service after the IIS service?

Tags: iis, windows-service, tomcat

I have both Apache and IIS on a Windows Server 2k3. The Apache server is reached by tunneling through IIS using the [Apache Tomcat Redirector](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/iis.html)

Everything works just fine until I reboot. When I do apparently the Apache Tomcat 6 service starts before the World Wide Web Publishing (W3SVC) service. Manually stopping and restarting the Apache Tomcat service fixes the problem, but I don't want to have to continue to do it manually every time I reboot.

How can I get Windows to start Apache after IIS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the Apache service to be dependant on `W3SVC`. From an elevated command prompt:

```
sc config ApacheServiceName depend= W3SVC
```

Note the space after the equals next to "depend". It needs to be there. Replace ApacheServiceName with the service name (not the display name) of your apache service.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/193888

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is add the W3SVC service as a dependency to Tomcat so that Tomcat will wait for the W3SVC service to start first.

To add a dependency to a service you can do it using the `sc` command from the command prompt

```
sc config <service name> depend= <dependencies>
```